# Making a hidden sliding div appear behind link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/564yzug3/1/)

Please see the fiddle above.

There is a link which when clicked a hidden div slides out from the right.

The hidden div contains an image.

At the moment the hidden div slides out but appears at a distance from the 'contact' link, and then when it slides back it disappears before it slides behind 'contact'.

I want it to appear to slide out form behind 'contact' and back in behind 'contact' without any overlapping.

```
$('#contact').click(function () {
$('#contact-info').animate({width: 'toggle'});
});
```

Comment: Reduce #contact-info right css property to 90px;

Comment: #contact-info{right:90px;}

Comment: try adjusting the css property "right". Currently right property is set to 160px. set it to 79px

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/564yzug3/9/ ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that once the div has slid out it needs to be set at this distance from the link, but somehow appear as if sliding out from behind to that distance from the right.

Comment: A downvote without a comment? Let me fix that for ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this by simply adjusting the css. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/564yzug3/12/)

```
#contact {
background-color: #ffffff;
bottom: 34px;
padding-right: 38px;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
#contact-info {
bottom: 34px;
margin-right: -250px;
position: fixed;
right: 444px;
text-transform: lowercase;
white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
var move = 80;
$('#contact').click(function () {
         move = move===80 ? 160 : 80;
    $('#contact-info').animate({right: move, width: 'toggle' });
});
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/564yzug3/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Animate the `right` property as well.

```
$('#contact').click(function () {
    var right = '160px';
    if ($('#contact-info').is(":visible")) {
        right = '38px';
    }
    $('#contact-info').animate({width: 'toggle', right: right});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RichAyotte/cs23vzjv/1/